# Symbol to denote a credulous consequence

Tags: logic

I have been trying to find the correct symbol to denote a credulous consequence. I've only been successful in finding the symbol for skeptical consequence, does a symbol for credulous consequence exist? If so, what is it?

Comment: Can you put the symbols you know into the answer as a table or chart? I'd be interested in learning more of what you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just use the standard symbol for consequence, the credulity is implied.  This should work, unless you happen to be working in a system that actually requires three differentiable types of consequence (skeptical, credulous, standard).

Answer (score 1):

If there is no such symbol, one can be easily created by "inversion" of the existing symbol. If skeptical consequence is **sc**, then credulous consequence would be,**-sc**.  Or contact the "entity" responsible for the creation and standardization of symbols and request/propose the creation of such symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same symbol because skeptical and credulous rely in the same principle: not formal demonstration or proof exist. The "consequences" (sic.) lies on probability heaven :)